# Send APNS subtitle with Firebase

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications

I'm looking at switching to Firebase for our push notification delivery. The one thing I can't find documentation on is the subtitle property for APNS alerts. Alternatively, is there a way to manually specify the APNS payload format and content?

Comment: reading from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1) my guess is it should be in the **same** hierarchy that the `title` key is. Meaning it should be a key of the `alert` object.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in Firebase where you can specify the APNS payload. There is the notification key, which has body and title, but adding subtitle there doesn't seem to get passed through.

Comment: I'm sorry David, I've never worked with FB. Don't know. I just remember before I saw a panel where you can add your keys value pairs. If that doesn't work then I don't know. Sometimes Firebase has its own substitute name for keys.

Comment: @DavidBeck did you find solution ?